# API Gateway endpoint works on AWS Console but not in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway endpoint that proxies a Lambda function. When I test the endpoint in the console (a GET request), it works fine and returns the correct JSON.

When I try the same endpoint in the browser or Postman, it doesn't work. The error is:

server IP address could not be found

I have logs set up in CloudWatch for the API and nothing comes up, so it looks like the API is not even getting called.

I'm using the serverless framework with NodeJS. I've tried deleting my whole CloudFormation stack and redeploying from scratch but it didn't make a difference. The API was working fine until today.

Comment: Did you set up a custom domain for your API Gateway? it looks like a DNS issue !

Comment: No I haven't, it's the default url. I found that the API stops working when I'm using public wifi (eg Starbucks) but not 3G or normal wifi

Comment: Try using cloudfare or Google's DNS (1.1.1.1 or  8.8.8.8 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the exact same issue. Specificially, Starbucks wifi doesn't like AWS API Gateway endpoints but quite a few other public wifi too. The solution is to use custom domain for the API Gateway endpoints, I'm afraid